# How to get intending data from an ajax response with a shorter key in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In a shopping app, I want to use ajax to instantly update the total price of cart.

Related code in `views/carts/index`:

```
$("input#number").change(function(){
  var current_quantity = $(this).val();
  var url = $(this).closest("form").attr("action");
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "PATCH",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      number: current_quantity
    },
    complete: function(data){
      $("#total_price").text(data["total_price"]);
    }
  })
});
```

Then at the end of `cart_items_controller.rb` 's `update` , this line:

```
render json: {total_price: "#{current_cart.cal_price}"}
```

---

After changing the quantity of cart_item in the form, the `:quantity` updated successfully, and in chrome dev tool I checked the response is code like this:

```
{"total_price":"214092"}
```

But I can't use `data["total_price]` or `data.total_price` to capture the number.

If I use `console.log(data)` it returns a whole http response object in console:

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ ( statusText )
always: ƒ ()
complete: ƒ ()
done: ƒ ()
.
.
.
responseJSON: {total_price: "197053"}
.
.

Object
```

I must use `data.responseJSON.total_price` to get the value I want.

**If there something wrong with my code? How can I get the value by only using a simpler `data["total_price"]` or `data.total_price`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a whole http response object because you're passing a callback function to `complete` (which gets passed a `jqXHR` type, the 'whole http response' you refer to) rather than `success` (which gets passed only the responseJson). From the jQuery docs:

> The jQuery XMLHttpRequest (jqXHR) object returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 is a superset of the browser's native XMLHttpRequest object. For example, it contains responseText and responseXML properties.
>
> ([Source](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))

Change

```
complete: function(data){
  $("#total_price").text(data["total_price"]);
}
```

To

```
success: function(data){
  $("#total_price").text(data["total_price"]);
}
```

Or, as seems to be the more idiomatic version nowadays:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "PATCH",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        number: current_quantity
    }
})
.done(function(data) {
    $("#total_price").text(data["total_price"]);
});
```